# ANTLR4 doesn't find any tokens on a certain machine but works fine on mine with same input file

Tags: c++, c++17, antlr, antlr4

My program uses the ANTLR (v4.8.0) C++ target for parsing. Now there is one machine, which I cannot access for fault-tracing, on which

`line 1:0 mismatched input '<EOF>'`

is reported for an input file which works fine on my machine. The error message makes me believe that ANTLR doesn't find a single token, it's like it was passed an empty stream. The input file is encoded with UTF8-BOM.

Both my machine and the one on which it doesn't work runs Windows 10.

The code which loads the input stream is

```
antlr4::ANTLRInputStream antlrIs(inputAsUtf8);
A2lLexer lexer(&antlrIs);
lexer.removeErrorListeners();
lexer.addErrorListener(errorListener);
antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
// The strategy from https://groups.google.com/g/antlr-discussion/c/q-8MPVI9lrw has been tested 
// and found to yield the same performance as this basic one.
XParser parser(&tokens);
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);
XParser::XFileContext* xFileContext = parser.xFile();
if (lexer.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() || parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors())
{
   throw runtime_error((string("Syntax error in ") + inputFile + ".").c_str());
}
```

The content of `inputAsUtf8`looks fine when printed to console.

Any ideas on how to fault-trace this furher? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a parser problem. Rewrite the code to call the lexer nextToken() in a loop until EOF and see what the lexer is returning. If it is returning only EOF, step into the Antlr runtime lexer and see why. The runtime is downloaded and built via CMake builds.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that for some reason the ifstream source sometimes is empty. Hence this wasn't related to ANTLR but actually to ifstream.